# Polygon grid and raster layer do not align R

Tags: raster, r, leaflet, vector-grid, alignment

I noticed that polygons and raster cells are not perfectly aligned.
Why the border of the cells and the colors do not align perfectly? There is a little misalignment (the colors do not change exactly at the border).

Below a minimal implementation to reproduce the problem (I am using R).

Chirps input file is `chirps-v2.0.2020.04.06.tif` from here:
https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/global_daily/tifs/p05/2020/

Shape file from GADM (using unpacked Colombia shapefile):
https://gadm.org/download_country.html#google_vignette

```
pckgs <- c('raster','sf','tidyverse','mapview','leaflet','RColorBrewer')

install.packages(setdiff(pckgs, rownames(installed.packages())))
invisible(lapply(pckgs, library, character.only=T, quietly=T))

stopifnot(file.exists("chirps-v2.0.2020.04.06.tif"))
stopifnot(file.exists("./gadm41_COL_shp/gadm41_COL_1.shp"))
precip <- raster("chirps-v2.0.2020.04.06.tif")

colombia <- st_read("./gadm41_COL_shp/gadm41_COL_2.shp")
aoi <- filter(colombia, NAME_2 == "Tolú")
precip.crop <- raster::crop(precip, extent(aoi))
precip.mask <- mask(x = precip.crop, mask = aoi)

pal <- colorNumeric(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "darkblue"), values(precip.mask),
                      na.color = "transparent")
polygs <- rasterToPolygons(precip.mask)
grd <- st_make_grid(polygs,c(res(precip.mask)))
p <- st_as_sf(polygs)
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addRasterImage(precip.mask, colors = pal, opacity = 0.6) %>%
                   addPolygons(data=p, color='black',weight=0.5)
mapshot(m, file = "col2sh2.png",vwidth = 992*4,vheight=744*4,opacity=0)
```

As you see by looking at col2sh2.png, the grid lines and the coloring do not perfectly align.

Why is that?

[image: This is the mapshot produced by the script]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the border of the cells and the colors do not match? There is a little misalignment.

Comment: This gets worse towards the bottom of the image, yes? There's a red grid cell above a blue grid cell and you can just make out the grid line isn't on the boundary. Do you get the same discrepancy when viewing the map in a browser? Because I see a much tinier discrepancy that isn't really visible on the max zoom allowed with an OSM tile layer, but if I map without it I can zoom further in. Tiny tiny discrepancy. Do you only see it when making an image with `mapshot`? (mapshot requires PhantomJS which I've not got)

Comment: Hi @Spacedman thank you very much. Yes, the mismatch has a dependency on the latitude, can be worse at different latitudes and can be larger than in this small example. 
Yes, the mismatch is visible also without mapshot, that is, when leaflet opens the map in the browser.
To the best of my knowledge, the polygons (grid lines) are correct, and the problem is with the coloring scheme.